# DPDT (110V) with memory

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, dpdt, latching-relay

I have one switch that should control two power lines (A and B) with lamps.

```
Switcher OFF - A OFF, B OFF
Switcher ON - A ON, B OFF
Switcher OFF - A OFF, B OFF
Switcher ON - A OF, B ON
...
Switcher OFF - A OFF, B OFF
Switcher ON - A ON, B OFF
Switcher OFF - A OFF, B OFF
Switcher ON - A OF, B ON
```

Could somebody recommend what working solution i can use for it?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is easily changed to D FF's or NAND gates for active low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw2RRo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>